How to use the plt. contourf() function to draw contour lines when there is a significant difference in magnitude
I want to use the plt. contourf() function to draw contour lines and draw the following image.
enter image description here
But the drawn effect is like this.
enter image description here
My data has the following characteristics:,

The difference in data magnitude is quite large, ranging from negative 11th power of 10 to positive 5th power of 10.
The number of elevation points is 80 * 80
About my thoughts and questions.
Is the contourf() function unable to draw the level of precision of the example graph.
Such a large difference in data size, but with only 80 * 80 points, is it impossible to draw the effect as shown in the figure.
How to set the range of logarithmic scale I want in colorbar()?

My code is as follows
def draw_contour():
    np_array=np.load("terrain.npy")
    x,y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,80,80),np.linspace(0,80,80))
    plt.contourf(x,y,np_array[:,0].reshape(80,80),levels=100000,locator=ticker.LogLocator(),alpha=1,linestyles='--',cmap='terrain')
    plt.colorbar(label='Elevation')    
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()
    print('end')

if __name__=='__main__':
    draw_contour()

Here are a part of my data:
1.599047500000000004e-09 1.313549499999999921e-09 2.957425000000000259e-09 6.581700000000000133e-09 1.403785499999999981e-08 1.061308999999999938e-08 1.348184999999999972e-08 2.813344999999999904e-08 2.813889999999999927e-08 6.593084999999999510e-08 4.467239999999999972e-08 9.216970000000000774e-08 1.199795000000000057e-07 1.266535000000000032e-07 1.628744999999999938e-07 2.174800000000000125e-07 2.680564999999999889e-07 3.482195000000000166e-07 4.478609999999999629e-07 6.015924999999999919e-07 6.991690000000000054e-07 9.022254999999999814e-07 1.082098000000000138e-06 1.211669999999999997e-06 1.579855000000000140e-06 1.807479999999999930e-06 2.053945000000000119e-06 2.327974999999999933e-06 3.122684999999999986e-06 3.711414999999999938e-06 4.546999999999999833e-06 4.964809999999999311e-06 5.417750000000000772e-06 5.684454999999999771e-06 5.768959999999999904e-06 5.680670000000000111e-06 5.783034999999999426e-06 6.251639999999999830e-06 6.528230000000000006e-06 6.932649999999999600e-06 7.512599999999999866e-06 8.127784999999999296e-06 8.237690000000000068e-06 8.085139999999999301e-06 8.214044999999999382e-06 7.140290000000000207e-06 6.213300000000000295e-06 4.924879999999999509e-06 3.793549999999999873e-06 3.136120000000000053e-06 2.634600000000000152e-06 2.143420000000000224e-06 1.861609999999999952e-06 1.693629999999999953e-06 1.369885000000000014e-06 1.172089999999999903e-06 9.570600000000000745e-07 7.322484999999999146e-07 6.445674999999999913e-07 4.931660000000000103e-07 3.772570000000000012e-07 3.313564999999999800e-07 2.411370000000000237e-07 2.197959999999999917e-07 1.221715000000000031e-07 9.561480000000000197e-08 7.027140000000000282e-08 4.637055000000000093e-08 3.699664999999999797e-08 3.595509999999999881e-08 1.615459999999999961e-08 1.293254999999999956e-08 1.561520000000000208e-08 5.520590000000000268e-09 1.249054499999999970e-08 4.033669999999999782e-09 2.918890000000000040e-09 2.194874999999999826e-09 2.593430000000000215e-09 1.713230999999999995e-09
1.717760000000000074e-09 2.730614999999999881e-09 4.694524999999999978e-09 4.423450000000000477e-09 1.250166000000000085e-08 1.678816999999999911e-08 2.667375000000000087e-08 3.025714999999999906e-08 6.459900000000000822e-08 9.240324999999999066e-08 1.006696000000000057e-07 1.284040000000000161e-07 1.766920000000000048e-07 2.041970000000000119e-07 2.958125000000000159e-07 4.046420000000000045e-07 4.487385000000000447e-07 5.517469999999999708e-07 6.990484999999999614e-07 8.555759999999999845e-07 1.211015000000000127e-06 1.493704999999999914e-06 1.875334999999999977e-06 2.117339999999999874e-06 2.690965000000000247e-06 3.052610000000000069e-06 3.750235000000000017e-06 4.785575000000000340e-06 5.876430000000000588e-06 7.272519999999999956e-06 8.127759999999999241e-06 9.176440000000000185e-06 9.718989999999998913e-06 9.541909999999999924e-06 1.009613500000000053e-05 9.358070000000000681e-06 9.412449999999999981e-06 9.943400000000000377e-06 1.019169999999999934e-05 1.135549999999999995e-05 1.236460000000000017e-05 1.336515000000000027e-05 1.402880000000000026e-05 1.456100000000000001e-05 1.409154999999999894e-05 1.271280000000000134e-05 1.121449999999999910e-05 8.775780000000000196e-06 7.384385000000000620e-06 5.618095000000000121e-06 5.211115000000000166e-06 4.157110000000000251e-06 3.368279999999999877e-06 2.866249999999999874e-06 2.511964999999999928e-06 1.715265000000000001e-06 1.568704999999999832e-06 1.194760000000000145e-06 1.007740500000000063e-06 7.623405000000000493e-07 6.426074999999999922e-07 4.934790000000000740e-07 3.598349999999999925e-07 2.904885000000000140e-07 2.397254999999999717e-07 1.250329999999999788e-07 1.138895000000000088e-07 6.854760000000000429e-08 6.385954999999999958e-08 3.621410000000000133e-08 2.733829999999999937e-08 3.806825000000000076e-08 1.726340000000000224e-08 1.447940000000000027e-08 8.468105000000000507e-09 6.807524999999999609e-09 7.171535000000000299e-09 2.633965000000000220e-09 2.297965000000000139e-09 5.165630000000000080e-09
4.846629999999999837e-09 8.881695000000000109e-09 1.353762999999999971e-08 1.354510000000000030e-08 1.824784499999999925e-08 4.306010000000000188e-08 4.959240000000000010e-08 5.829675000000000220e-08 1.005454499999999959e-07 1.091780000000000000e-07 1.352439999999999900e-07 1.935979999999999843e-07 3.525489999999999893e-07 3.263290000000000100e-07 4.202960000000000202e-07 6.144104999999999681e-07 7.485635000000000710e-07 9.993590000000000485e-07 1.220029999999999947e-06 1.600339999999999995e-06 1.906590000000000028e-06 2.352729999999999919e-06 3.011635000000000008e-06 3.759529999999999731e-06 4.640080000000000135e-06 5.420034999999999683e-06 6.620405000000000525e-06 8.357620000000000798e-06 1.018849499999999875e-05 1.185240000000000023e-05 1.379620000000000015e-05 1.488564999999999867e-05 1.499419999999999952e-05 1.503659999999999932e-05 1.530024999999999975e-05 1.485160000000000194e-05 1.515205000000000005e-05 1.534134999999999839e-05 1.654879999999999985e-05 1.811290000000000068e-05 1.996730000000000109e-05 2.187670000000000012e-05 2.291240000000000106e-05 2.484685000000000081e-05 2.450970000000000015e-05 2.189334999999999936e-05 1.978224999999999851e-05 1.686689999999999940e-05 1.423864999999999961e-05 1.105109999999999995e-05 9.298725000000001336e-06 6.885344999999999720e-06 6.147815000000000023e-06 4.595684999999999690e-06 3.951794999999999660e-06 3.078065000000000319e-06 2.318540000000000166e-06 1.961505000000000120e-06 1.554309999999999947e-06 1.141895000000000101e-06 8.875800000000000638e-07 6.334870000000000132e-07 4.664045000000000125e-07 3.758540000000000250e-07 3.152184999999999979e-07 2.033209999999999980e-07 1.327670000000000135e-07 1.008535999999999893e-07 9.972514999999998954e-08 4.822085000000000394e-08 3.576385000000000032e-08 3.124864999999999838e-08 1.520119999999999916e-08 1.525504999999999935e-08 1.453566499999999935e-08 1.029649999999999893e-08 3.329635000000000155e-09 4.264949999999999422e-09 2.436085000000000072e-09 1.908301999999999931e-09
3.481264999999999972e-09 1.128630500000000056e-08 1.127787999999999994e-08 2.813600000000000127e-08 2.404814999999999951e-08 6.056395000000000281e-08 8.843645000000000308e-08 8.425260000000001158e-08 1.132795000000000053e-07 1.832730000000000027e-07 2.381274999999999861e-07 3.445934999999999814e-07 4.612409999999999941e-07 5.505140000000000286e-07 7.409724999999999602e-07 8.774025000000000244e-07 1.199309999999999957e-06 1.575709999999999860e-06 2.024420000000000177e-06 2.484170000000000307e-06 2.988189999999999760e-06 3.836089999999999723e-06 4.907730000000000020e-06 5.798799999999999436e-06 6.961005000000000279e-06 8.864649999999999906e-06 1.104328000000000009e-05 1.344950000000000057e-05 1.601009999999999771e-05 1.957140000000000035e-05 2.192739999999999948e-05 2.367395000000000057e-05 2.356735000000000061e-05 2.390560000000000029e-05 2.363659999999999999e-05 2.301985000000000289e-05 2.293939999999999928e-05 2.367284999999999816e-05 2.521669999999999863e-05 2.836284999999999899e-05 3.234799999999999590e-05 3.519449999999999651e-05 3.884125000000000018e-05 3.919520000000000041e-05 4.038320000000000326e-05 3.809240000000000141e-05 3.530155000000000424e-05 3.109055000000000000e-05 2.627979999999999867e-05 2.049425000000000118e-05 1.722475000000000140e-05 1.385034999999999861e-05 1.092630000000000074e-05 8.487534999999998689e-06 6.726669999999999922e-06 5.244670000000000389e-06 4.106904999999999941e-06 3.232874999999999943e-06 2.406815000000000181e-06 1.564155000000000019e-06 1.242770000000000004e-06 9.366610000000000518e-07 7.408235000000000824e-07 5.243679999999999743e-07

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

If you want to adjust the log-scale range, take a look at the documentation for LogLocator. You should be able to put a vmin= and vmax= to change your upper and lower bounds. Secondly, it would be helpful to upload your dataset on a a separate platform for us to access and play around with, as opposed to the copy/pasted values you have at the end of your post. It is unclear to me how to use this to reproduce your problem.

Thank you for your answer sincerely.I have just entered stackhoverflow recently ,and i did realized that my language was not yet so concise. Last night, I did think about how to put my processed data on it, but I don't know which platform is suitable. Do you have any recommendations? Thanks

One possible approach is the following. Note that I apply a circular mask:
sample_data = np.array([
    1.5990475e-09, 1.3135495e-09, 2.9574250e-09, 6.5817e-09, 1.4037855e-08,
    1.0613090e-08, 1.3481850e-08, 2.8133449e-08, 2.8138899e-08, 6.5930850e-08,
    4.4672400e-08, 9.2169700e-08, 1.1997950e-07, 1.2665350e-07, 1.6287450e-07,
    2.1748000e-07, 2.6805650e-07, 3.4821950e-07, 4.4786096e-07, 6.0159250e-07,
    6.9916900e-07, 9.0222550e-07, 1.0820980e-06, 1.2116700e-06, 1.5798550e-06,
    1.8074800e-06, 2.0539450e-06, 2.3279750e-06, 3.1226850e-06, 3.7114150e-06,
    4.5470000e-06, 4.9648100e-06, 5.4177500e-06, 5.6844550e-06, 5.7689600e-06,
    5.6806700e-06, 5.7830350e-06, 6.2516400e-06, 6.5282300e-06, 6.9326500e-06,
    7.5126000e-06, 8.1277850e-06, 8.2376900e-06, 8.0851400e-06, 8.2140450e-06,
    7.1402900e-06, 6.2133000e-06, 4.9248800e-06, 3.7935500e-06, 3.1361200e-06,
    2.6346000e-06, 2.1434200e-06, 1.8616100e-06, 1.6936300e-06, 1.3698850e-06,
    1.1720900e-06, 9.5706000e-07, 7.3224850e-07, 6.4456750e-07, 4.9316600e-07,
    3.7725700e-07, 3.3135650e-07, 2.4113700e-07, 2.1979600e-07, 1.2217150e-07,
    9.5614800e-08, 7.0271400e-08, 4.6370550e-08, 3.6996650e-08, 3.5955100e-08,
    1.6154600e-08, 1.2932550e-08, 1.5615200e-08, 5.5205900e-09, 1.2490545e-08,
    4.0336700e-09, 2.9188900e-09, 2.1948750e-09, 2.5934300e-09, 1.7132310e-09,
    1.7177600e-09, 2.7306150e-09, 4.6945250e-09, 4.4234500e-09, 1.2501660e-08,
    1.6788170e-08, 2.6673750e-08, 3.0257150e-08, 6.4599000e-08, 9.2403250e-08,
    1.0066960e-07, 1.2840400e-07, 1.7669200e-07, 2.0419700e-07, 2.9581250e-07,
    4.0464200e-07, 4.4873850e-07, 5.5174700e-07, 6.9904850e-07, 8.5557600e-07,
    1.2110150e-06, 1.4937050e-06, 1.8753350e-06, 2.1173400e-06, 2.6909650e-06,
    3.0526100e-06, 3.7502350e-06, 4.7855750e-06, 5.8764300e-06, 7.2725200e-06,
    8.1277600e-06, 9.1764400e-06, 9.7189900e-06, 9.5419100e-06, 1.0096135e-05,
    9.3580700e-06, 9.4124500e-06, 9.9434000e-06, 1.0191700e-05, 1.1355500e-05,
    1.2364600e-05, 1.3365150e-05, 1.4028800e-05, 1.4561000e-05, 1.4091550e-05,
    1.2712800e-05, 1.1214500e-05, 8.7757800e-06, 7.3843850e-06, 5.6180950e-06,
    5.2111150e-06, 4.1571100e-06, 3.3682800e-06, 2.8662500e-06, 2.5119650e-06,
    1.7152650e-06, 1.5687050e-06, 1.1947600e-06, 1.0077405e-06, 7.6234050e-07,
    6.4260750e-07, 4.9347900e-07, 3.5983500e-07, 2.9048850e-07, 2.3972550e-07,
    1.2503300e-07, 1.1388950e-07, 6.8547600e-08, 6.3859550e-08, 3.6214100e-08,
    2.7338300e-08, 3.8068250e-08, 1.7263400e-08, 1.4479400e-08, 8.4681050e-09,
    6.8075250e-09, 7.1715350e-09, 2.6339650e-09, 2.2979650e-09, 5.1656300e-09,
    4.8466300e-09, 8.8816950e-09, 1.3537630e-08, 1.3545100e-08, 1.8247845e-08,
    4.3060100e-08, 4.9592400e-08, 5.8296750e-08, 1.0054545e-07, 1.0917800e-07,
    1.3524400e-07, 1.9359800e-07, 3.5254900e-07, 3.2632900e-07, 4.2029600e-07,
    6.1441050e-07, 7.4856350e-07, 9.9935900e-07, 1.2200300e-06, 1.6003400e-06,
    1.9065900e-06, 2.3527300e-06, 3.0116350e-06, 3.7595300e-06, 4.6400800e-06,
    5.4200350e-06, 6.6204050e-06, 8.3576200e-06, 1.0188495e-05, 1.1852400e-05,
    1.3796200e-05, 1.4885650e-05, 1.4994200e-05, 1.5036600e-05, 1.5300250e-05,
    1.4851600e-05, 1.5152050e-05, 1.5341350e-05, 1.6548800e-05, 1.8112900e-05,
    1.9967300e-05, 2.1876700e-05, 2.2912400e-05, 2.4846850e-05, 2.4509700e-05,
    2.1893350e-05, 1.9782250e-05, 1.6866900e-05, 1.4238650e-05, 1.1051100e-05,
    9.2987250e-06, 6.8853450e-06, 6.1478150e-06, 4.5956850e-06, 3.9517950e-06,
    3.0780650e-06, 2.3185400e-06, 1.9615050e-06, 1.5543100e-06, 1.1418950e-06,
    8.8758000e-07, 6.3348700e-07, 4.6640450e-07, 3.7585400e-07, 3.1521850e-07,
    2.0332100e-07, 1.3276700e-07, 1.0085360e-07, 9.9725150e-08, 4.8220850e-08,
    3.5763850e-08, 3.1248650e-08, 1.5201200e-08, 1.5255050e-08, 1.4535665e-08,
    1.0296500e-08, 3.3296350e-09, 4.2649500e-09, 2.4360850e-09, 1.9083020e-09,
    3.4812650e-09, 1.1286305e-08, 1.1277880e-08, 2.8136000e-08, 2.4048150e-08,
    6.0563950e-08, 8.8436450e-08, 8.4252600e-08, 1.1327950e-07, 1.8327300e-07,
    2.3812750e-07, 3.4459350e-07, 4.6124100e-07, 5.5051400e-07, 7.4097250e-07,
    8.7740250e-07, 1.1993100e-06, 1.5757100e-06, 2.0244200e-06, 2.4841700e-06,
    2.9881900e-06, 3.8360900e-06, 4.9077300e-06, 5.7988000e-06, 6.9610050e-06,
    8.8646500e-06, 1.1043280e-05, 1.3449500e-05, 1.6010100e-05, 1.9571400e-05,
    2.1927400e-05, 2.3673950e-05, 2.3567350e-05, 2.3905600e-05, 2.3636600e-05,
    2.3019850e-05, 2.2939400e-05, 2.3672850e-05, 2.5216700e-05, 2.8362850e-05,
    3.2348000e-05, 3.5194500e-05, 3.8841250e-05, 3.9195200e-05, 4.0383200e-05,
    3.8092400e-05, 3.5301550e-05, 3.1090550e-05, 2.6279800e-05, 2.0494250e-05,
    1.7224750e-05, 1.3850350e-05, 1.0926300e-05, 8.4875350e-06, 6.7266700e-06,
    5.2446700e-06, 4.1069050e-06, 3.2328750e-06, 2.4068150e-06, 1.5641550e-06,
    1.2427700e-06, 9.3666100e-07, 7.4082350e-07, 5.2436800e-07
])


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def apply_circular_mask(np_array, radius=None):
    if radius is None:
        radius = np_array.shape[1] / 2

    l = np_array.shape[0]
    x = np.linspace(-l/2, l/2, l)
    y = np.linspace(-l/2, l/2, l)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    mask = (x**2 + y**2) > radius**2
    np_array[mask] = np.nan

    return np_array, x, y

def draw_contour(np_array):
    np_array, x, y = apply_circular_mask(np_array)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    min_val, max_val = np.nanmin(np_array), np.nanmax(np_array)
    levels = np.logspace(np.log10(min_val), np.log10(max_val), num=50)
    
    contourf = ax.contourf(x, y, np_array, levels=levels, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val), cmap='terrain', extend='both')
    plt.colorbar(contourf, label='Elevation (m)', format=ticker.LogFormatterMathtext())

    ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
    ax.set_xlabel('Eastwise Ground Distance (km)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Northwise Ground Distance (km)')
    ax.set_title('Contour Plot with Logarithmic Color Scale')
    
    ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

    plt.show()


np_array = sample_data
a = np_array.size
np_array = np_array * (10 ** (np.random.rand(a, a)))

draw_contour(np_array)


wich gives


Thank you for your help. I have tried your method and learned how to set the scale. Unfortunately, he still did not achieve the accuracy I wanted.I think there may be a problem my data. I will try other tools and continue to share my steps to solve this problem here. Also, could you please leave your email? If possible, I would like to send you a copy of data.npy. Thank you very much

You can find my email in my profile
